# Getting System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException while trying to Authenticate in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I am trying to learn Authorization in MVC and i started a new project and when i try to call the http://localhost:64981/Account/Login page i am getting an error like this[image]
here is the code of my controller

```
[Authorize]
    [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Account/Login

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }
}
```

what exactly is wrong and how to resolve this issue, thank you

Comment: This error can occur when you are trying to assign a value to something that has not yet been loaded. To say something more detailed about what is wrong, the stack trace would helpful.

Comment: @Hagbourne well !!! so how to should i call the account/login page then?

Comment: I am not talking about the fact that you are loading the page.. some artifact that the code is assigning a value to might not yet have been ready for it..and the stack trace could give you a clue as to what. This has been the case when I have encountered this error in the past.